# Non Classical Examples of Indecomposable Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

A classical example of a ring $R$ with an indecomposable ideal is the ring $C(X)$ of real valued continuous functions on $X$, where the $(0)$ ideal is not decomposable.
Does anyone know other examples of rings with a non decomposable ideal?
(In particular, I'm looking for a non reduced one.)

Comment: I think it's completely unnecessary to edit in a "thank you" message on behalf of the OP.

Comment: What do you mean by an "indecomposable ideal"?

Comment: An ideal such that it doesn't possess a primary decomposition.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207406/irreducible-components-of-the-prime-spectrum-of-a-quotient-ring-and-primary-deco/207468#207468). (Btw, you can add the definition of indecomposable ideals into the body of your question.)