# Detecting compactness from the ring of smooth functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology

Given a smooth manifold $M$, is there some ring-theoretic property (preferably not mentioning $M$) such that $C^{\infty}(M)$ has this property if and only if $M$ is compact?

Comment: And why are we down-voting?

Comment: A wild guess: $C^\infty(M)$ admits a set $E$ of ring homomorphisms $\ell : C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ which separates points (if $\ell(f) = 0$ for all $\ell \in E$ then $f=0$) and such that for each $f$, $\sup_E |\ell(f)| < \infty$.  (Of course, I'm thinking of $\ell$ as evaluation maps, and I'm trying to detect whether $M$ admits an unbounded smooth function.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Dmitri Pavlov claims](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21173/19593) $M$ is compact iff all maximal ideals of $C^\infty(M)$ of  codimension $1$. For a more about algebraic properties of $C^\infty(M)$ see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22065/algebraic-properties-of-the-algebra-of-continuous-functions-on-a-manifold) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5344/algebraic-description-of-compact-smooth-manifolds) MO discussions.

Comment: Norbert: Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following is an answer courtesy of a brighter friend:

> $M$ is compact iff every maximal ideal in $C^{\infty}(M)$ is finitely-generated

If $M$ is compact, one can show that every maximal ideal is the kernel of some evaluation map and use Hadamard's Lemma to show that it is finitely-generated, as was done in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183199/commutative-non-noetherian-rings-in-which-all-maximal-ideals-are-finitely-genera). Conversely, if $M$ is not compact one can find a maximal ideal not finitely generated, as indicated in Exercise 8.20 in Nestruev's '*Smooth Manifolds and Observables*.'

Comment: have commutative algebraists ever thought to give a name to ring in which all maximal ideals are finitely-generated? (semi-noetherian, maybe?)

Comment: not at all${}{}{}$