# Finitely generated ideal containing non finitely generated ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I've been thinking about the following Rotman's exercise, and just can't find an answer:

> Give an example of a commutative ring $R$ containing proper ideals $I\subsetneq J\subsetneq R$ with $J$ finitely generated but with $I$ not finitely generated.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183199/commutative-non-noetherian-rings-in-which-all-maximal-ideals-are-finitely-genera

Comment: Any example in a polynomial ring?

Answer (score 11):

Recall that if $R$ is Noetherian then any ideal is finitely generated. Hence to write down a counterexample you need a ring that is not Noetherian. For my money, the simplest example of such a ring is a polynomial algebra $k[x_1, x_2, \dots]$ in countably many variables. $J = (x_1)$ is a finitely generated proper ideal, and it has a proper subideal

$$I = (x_1 x_2, x_1 x_3, x_1 x_4, \dots)$$

which I claim is not finitely generated. Do you see why?

Comment: Nice one @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Would another example be $J=(x_1, x_2)$ and $I=(x_1x_2, x_1x_3, \dots)+(x_2x_3, x_2x_4, \dots)$?

Comment: Could you explain why I is not finitely generated?

Comment: @bananapeel: the minimum degree of an element of $I$ is $2$, and the degree-$2$ piece of $I$ is countable-dimensional. But if it were generated by $n$ elements, its degree-$2$ piece could be at most $n$-dimensional.