# Is there a domain which is not UFD but has a maximal principal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Maximal ideals in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, which are not UFD, are *not* principal. I wonder, however, a maximal ideal could be principal. Is there known example?
Also, I wonder the existence of UFD that has an maximal principal ideal. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I can't tell if this is necessary but $\Bbb Z[x]$ is a UFD, in case you thought otherwise.

Comment: Do you mean to require the ring to be a domain? If not, then $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ works for any composite n

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I confuse a ring and a domain because I have not learn about non-domain ring deeply. I am going to modify them.

Comment: In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$, the ideal $(\sqrt{-5})$ is maximal and principal. In fact,  $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$ has infinitely many principal prime ideals, and all these primes are also maximal (since  $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$ is a Dedekind domain)

Comment: @Mathmo123 Oh, I don't think $(\sqrt{-5})$ (I only consider the principal ideal generated by 2.) I realize that the answer sometimes hidden in obvious thing, again. Thanks

Comment: If $p\equiv 11,13,17,19\pmod{20}$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$ then $p\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a maximal principle ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are integral domains whose *all* maximal ideals are principal and which are not UFDs.

An example is $R=\mathbb Z+X\mathbb Q[X]$. It is a Bézout domain which is not a PID (see [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/exhibit-a-bezout-domain-that-is-not-a-pid/)), so it can't be a UFD. (Note that $R$ is not noetherian since the ideal $X\mathbb Q[X]$ is not finitely generated.) Its maximal ideals are of the form $pR$, with $p\in\mathbb Z$ prime, and $fR$, with $f\in\mathbb Q[X]$ irreducible and $f(0)=1$.

Another example is a valuation ring with value group $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/183230/121097).)

Comment: What form are the maximal ideals? Are they all just $(p, X)$ for $p$ prime? Just wondering what the trick is to seeing if this is a complete set, if so.

Comment: @rschwieb There are also those generated by the irreducible polynomials $f\in\mathbb Q[X]$ with $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Hm yes, there is more variety. But anyhow, what's the trick to seeing all maximal ideals are principal?

Comment: @rschwieb There is no trick: some contain $X$ and look like you noticed, and some don't and look like I said.

Comment: OK, so just proof by exhaustive description. Thanks

Comment: And in case anyone reads later, $(p,X)=(p)$

Comment: I have of course upvoted this excellent answer, but why is it community wiki ? Also, since the example does not allow for the usual tools (like Krull's Hauptidealsatz) because of non-noetherianness, I would be very grateful   if you were so kind as to succinctly sketch the proofs of  some properties of this ring, like non-noetherianness, description of its spectrum,  non factorialness, etc. I have the feeling that it would be a worthwhile investment of your time, since your post could then be used for future reference as a counter-example to many  assertions. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwaj It's a CW answer since the OP didn't actually asked this.

Comment: You are right that it's good to have at hand most of the properties of this remarkable ring, but here is not the right place to make an exhaustive investigation for the same reason I've made this answer CW.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, user26857.