# An ideal is maximal iff it is generated by an irreducible elemnt

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, maximal-and-prime-ideals

It is well known that in a **PID** an ideal is maximal iff it is generated by an irreducible element.
My query is '**is the result true only in a PID?**'.
My question is what will happen if the **PID** condition is removed.
That is I want to know if in an *ID* an ideal is maximal then is it necessary that it is not generated by an irreducible element? i.e if an *ID* is given then will we assume that no Maximal ideal can be generated by an irreducible element? 
And what about the converse ? i.e if an ideal is generated by an irreducible element in an *ID*,then will we assume that it is not maximal?
I am thinking that in an *ID* the results are not necessarily false,and my reason behind it is that 'maximal ideal $\Rightarrow$ it is generated by an irreducible element and the converse of it' doesn't characterize an PID.
I am not confident as I am unable to find any such example.
Sorry for the lengthy question.
Hope to get cleared.
Thank you

Comment: "Assume the ideal is not maximal" and "Not assume the ideal is maximal" are two _very_ different things.

Comment: Sorry sir I didn't get you.Will please explain.?

Comment: How about being more objective in your question?

Comment: In the noetherian case, if any maximal ideal of an integral domain is generated by one element (we dont even need to assume that it is irreducible), then it is a PID. In the non-noetherian case, there are counter examples, since principal ideals can have height $2$ in that scenario, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183199/commutative-non-noetherian-rings-in-which-all-maximal-ideals-are-finitely-genera