# When $R$ is not Noetherian, what happens to exercise 15.16 (p.296) of Sharp's book "Steps in Commutative Algebra"

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

[**Krull's height theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem) says that if $R$ is a **Noetherian** ring and $I$ is a proper ideal generated by $n$ elements of $R$, then $\operatorname{ht} I\le n$.
In the absence of the Noetherian hypothesis, the conclusion  fails.

When  $R$ is not Noetherian, what happens to exercise 15.16 (p.296) of Sharp's *Steps in Commutative Algebra* which says:
Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, and let $a\in R$ be a non-unit and a non-zerodivisor. Let $P \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ be such that $a\in P$. Prove that $\operatorname{ht}_{R/a}P/Ra=\operatorname{ht}_RP-1.$

Comment: I don't understand what's good for that preamble on Krull's principal ideal theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1244823/121097). Set $a=X$ and notice that $\operatorname{ht} P/(a)=0$ while $\operatorname{ht} P-1=1$.