# Domain strictly contained in the intersection of localizations at the primes of height one

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain

If $R$ is a Noetherian normal domain, then it is equal to the intersection of its localizations at height one primes.

> What is an example of a non-normal domain that is strictly contained in such an intersection?

I'd prefer an example that is a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, and all I want is a candidate suggested. I'd prefer to verify it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $R=k[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an easier example, but here is one I found after searching a bit, Ex. 7.2 in [this arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.03411v3) by Epstein and Shapiro. It is sadly not finitely generated nor noetherian, but it *is* normal!

Let $k$ be a field and $R = k[x,y,y/x,y/x^2,y/x^3,\ldots] \subset k(x,y)$, which you might have seen as part of Karl Schwede's [construction](https://mathoverflow.net/a/82095/33088) of a non-discrete valuation ring. The ideal $\mathfrak{m} = (x)$ is a height two principal prime ideal by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180910/116766), hence
$$ x^{-1} \in \left(\bigcap_{\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak{p} = 1} R_\mathfrak{p}\right) \setminus R. $$